# How can I generate a sequence of 10 RANDOM characters, then display them?

Tags: command-line

Do I need to use something like: head -c 10 /dev/urandom | xxd   ???
But that doesn't work as I want to. I need only 10 characters (a-z 0-9)

Thanks!

Comment: if you dont need quality ranom you can use ```mktemp -u XXXXXXXXXX```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this: `< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c10`

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: This would be rather wasteful. A better option might be to convert it to base64 and get 10 of those characters instead. (`base64 < /dev/urandom | head -c10`).

Comment: There are so many options available to solve this problem. This was just the first one which came to mind.